# Dispose objects before losing scope(SqlCommand)

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

How can i dispose of "command" before returning it without affecting the return type?
"Reability error CA2000 ([CA2000: Dispose objects before losing scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289.aspx))"

```
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd);
        command.CommandTimeout = 240;
        if (applicationId == int.MinValue)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApplicationId", DBNull.Value);
        else
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApplicationId", applicationId);


        return DB.ExecuteDataset(command);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the style of Jeapordy: "What is a `using` statement?"

```
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd))
{
    command.CommandTimeout = 240;
    if (applicationId == int.MinValue)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApplicationId", DBNull.Value);
    else
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApplicationId", applicationId);


    return DB.ExecuteDataset(command);
}
```

Comment: @BrunoMartins more generally: you should be using `using` quite a bit, especially on things like database resources.

Comment: @BrunoMartins and for a more complete treatment of what `using` means in this context: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: "The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the using statement is translated by the compiler. The code example earlier expands to the following code at compile time.."
Is it safe to say "i dont need to use try and catch"?

Comment: @BrunoMartins in this scenario, yes - the compiler is basically doing that *for you* (well, `try`/`finally`, actually)